# ANOVA (Change), ANCOVA, Linear Mixed Model for Repeated Measure in Python

Tags: anova, group-differences

I am rather new to the statistics and have read some different blogs already. Still I am not very clear in which statistical tool to use for my research question:

I have a **Control vs. Intervention - Trial** where each subject is **randomly assigned** to one of the groups. **Three measurements** are taken for each subject:

1. Baseline (no intervention at all)
2. Intermediate (after Part 1 of the Intervention / Control)
3. Post (after Part 2 of the Intervention / Control)

The time intervals do not really matter and are the same for everyone.
The measurement / dep. variable is a continous value on a visual analogue scale ranging from 0-100.

Now I want to investigate 2 Research Questions:
**

1. **Is there any pre-post effect between the groups?**
2. **Which of the treatment parts** (the one between baseline and intermediate measurement or the second one between intermediate and post measurement) **is contributing in which way?**

To the first question, whether there is an overall "positive" effect, i.e. if the "whole" treatment (which consists of Part 1 and Part 2) is influencing the outcome (higher values in the scale), I have read some discussions about "How to analyse Baseline - Post Changes":

- We could simply analyse the difference of pre to post using t-test between the two groups.
- We could use ANOVA instead with the absolute values as Within-Subject parameters and the condition as between-subject parameters.
- We could do an ANCOVA with the post-values as outcome and the baseline measurements as covariate.
- We could somehow generalize this using a linear mixed model.

I am still not clear which one to use if I only had the pre-post values.
However we also have the intermediate-measurements and it would be nice to combine the two research questions in one model. How to account for "regression to the mean" problem or ceiling effects?
I have thought of doing an ANOVA with the pre-intermediate and the intermediate-post changes. Would that make sense?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.: I am using Python / Statsmodels / Pingouin Library with long format data.